# Cannot Install Or Update Packages In Kali

Tags: debian, apt-get

I tried upgrading my debian packages with `apt-get upgrade` but then it throws the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 135 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/dpkg
```

You can have a look at [this post](https://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/debian-apt-get-installs-fail-with-dpkg-error-code-100/) and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944896/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-100-could-not-exec-dpkg) which addresses the same error code